# Html JavaScript Form Url update from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I just asked a question then realised it was the completely wrong question!

This is the form code I have

```
<form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/" method="post">
```

This form is a **Jquerymobile** page linked together.

In the functions page I have this for the data being put into a table

```
$('.listAllBugs').append('<tr class="table-stroke"><td>'+bugDetails+'</td><td><a href="#edit'+bug_id+'">Edit</a></td></tr>');
```

I'm needing the form url to have the `bug_id` transferred over to the edit page. So at the moment the `#edit` page doesn't update anything. I'm needing the ID to go after the `update/` above.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is append the `bug_id` to the `<form>`'s action, then where you populate the table you can add:

```
var $form = $('#bug-form');
$form.attr('action', $form.attr('action') + bug_id);
```